# Can we calculate/extract Virtual Table address some how from DIA SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pdb-files, dbghelp, dia-sdk

Can we extract vtable's starting base address of a type if it implements vtable functions from DIA SDK?

Regards,
Usman

Answer (score 0):

This is compiler dependent of course, but the first 4 bytes of an object (if it has 1 or more virtual functions) is a pointer to its vtable.

Comment: Object is not available at runtime. If some how I can extract base address of vtable or can offset it from base address of that type which contains vtable. For that I need to address of that type as well. I am not working with object. Suppose at runtime, I have no object at all.